# Middleware handler for Mobile and Browser API calls

Tags: django, web-services, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I want to develop a Django based web service where my web application (Platform:Angular JS) and mobile applications (Platform: iOS,android,Windows Phone) will communicate with it. 
 My django web service app only for handling API calls. For security reasons I chose Oauth toolkit for mobile application,for web Session Authentication?

Settings.py for Authentication,

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
),
```

### My problem:

1. I want to handle CSRF based authentication if I received a call from browser side.
2. Call Oauth authentication if I received call from Native Mobile client .
   How to diferentiate the two, and how to handle this authentication technique.

Need your help!!

Answer (score 0):

**You can use [`django-mobile`](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile) library to detect requests from mobile browsers and then call diferent authentication classes.**

`django-mobile` library defines `MobileDetectionMiddleware` and `SetFlavourMiddleware` middleware classes in it.

`MobileDetectionMiddleware` detects if the requests originated from a mobile or a web browser.

`SetFlavourMiddleware` class sets the `flavour` attribute in the request. There are 2 possible values for `flavour`:

```
'mobile' # Mobile requests
'full' # Web requests
```

After the correct flavour is somehow chosen by the middlewares, it's assigned to the `request.flavour` attribute.

**Step-1: Configure `django-mobile` in your application**

Follow the steps given in https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-mobile#installation to install and configure `django-mobile` in your application.

After it has been configured, you can just use `request.flavour` to check if request is from a mobile browser or a web browser.

**Step-2: Create a custom `WebSessionAuthentication` class**

Since you want to use OAuth's `OAuth2Authentication`for mobile application  and DRF's `SessionAuthentication` for web, we can create a custom `WebSessionAuthentication` class which will inherit from the DRF's `SessionAuthentication`.

This `WebSessionAuthentication` class will perform no authentication for mobile requests. In case of web requests, it will perform proper session authentication with CSRF checks.

```
from rest_framework.authentication import  SessionAuthentication

class WebSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):
    """
    Performs session authentication for web requests
    """

    def authenticate(self, request):
        """
        Returns a `User` if the request session currently has a logged in user 
        and request is a web request
        Otherwise returns `None`.
        """
        underlying_request = request._request # get the underlying HttpRequest object
        if underlying_request.flavour == 'mobile': # check if mobile request
            return None # No authentication performed for mobile requests

        # For web requests perform DRF's original session authentication    
        return super(WebSessionAuthentication, self).authenticate(request)
```

**Step-3: Create a custom `MobileOAuth2Authentication` class**

`MobileOAuth2Authentication` class performs authentication for only `mobile` requests i.e. having `.flavour` as `mobile`. No authentication is performed for `web` requests.

```
from oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework import OAuth2Authentication

class MobileOAuth2Authentication(OAuth2Authentication):
    """
    Performs outh2 authentication for mobile requests
    """

    def authenticate(self, request):
        """
        Returns two-tuple of (user, token) if mobile authentication succeeds,
        or None otherwise.
        """
        underlying_request = request._request # get the underlying HttpRequest object
        if underlying_request.flavour == 'full': # check if web request
            return None # No authentication performed for web requests

        # For mobile requests perform OAuth2's original authentication    
        return super(MobileOAuth2Authentication, self).authenticate(request)
```

**Step-4: Define your authentication classes in settings**

After creating custom `WebSessionAuthentication` and `MobileOuth2Authentication` authentication classes, define these authentication class in your project settings.

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'my_app.authentication.WebSessionAuthentication', # custom session authentication class for web requests
    'my_app.authentication.MobileOAuth2Authentication', # custom oauth2 authentication class for mobile requests
),
```

Comment: Thank u for ur response @Rahul.. I gonna develop Native mobile application with functionalities.. I'll not use web browsers..

Comment: So, what do you intend by web applications? Did you meant mobile browsers?

Comment: no..Web standalone app.. mobile native app..2 separate platforms

Comment: You can use the `User-Agent` header to differentiate between the two. The standalone web app and native app will have different user agents and you can check that in your code to know where the request came from.